# ANTLR Reading blocks of values

Tags: antlr

I have been working on this for more than 2 days without success.  It will be a common problem, but I can't find a solution.  I did do a search!

### Problem:

I have some data that I want to read in say, 5 values per line.  I know how many I want to read from a value read previously.  For example, 6 values to read, spread over 2 lines...

```
6
10 20 30 40 50
60
```

so after every 5 variables I want to read a new line.  If there are 0 variables, I want to skip the bit to do with this, and if I want to read an exact multiple of 5 variables, then I want to avoid duplicating the NL call.

I tried this...

```
varblock[ Integer count ]
@init{
Integer varIndex = 0;
}
    : { count > 0 }? ( dp=NUMBER { count--; varIndex++;  }
          { ( varIndex \% 5 ) == 0 }? NL { varIndex = 0; }
          )+ { varIndex > 0 }? => NL
    |
    ;
```

But I get...

```
failed predicate: { ( varIndex \% 5 ) == 0 }?
```

It might be that I misunderstand predicates.  I have several other predicates in my grammar that seem to work, but they are not of this type.  There, I am trying to skip bits of the grammar depending on the version of the input file.

Thanks.

Comment: Are `NL` significant in any of your rules?

Answer (score 0):

NL is just a line feed that is expected at the end of the input lines.

```
NL    :   ( '\n' | '\r' )+ ;
```

In other lines we read several other things such as...

"IPE270" "BS 7191 GR 355C" 0.0 0 0

and the values such as STRING, FLOAT, or NUMBER must be on those lines in expected sequences.  So if we encounter a NL before we have read the requisite data values, there is a syntax error.  So, perhaps the answer to your question is "Yes".

Perhaps I just (over?) simplified the example.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
 It was a problem of brackets.  I looked at the generated parser code to get a clue.

```
varblock[ Integer count ]
@init{
   Integer index = 0;
}
   : ( { count > 0 }? => ( NUMBER  { count--; index++; } 
                         | { (index \% 5) == 0 }? => NL ) )+ { index > 0 }? => NL
   |
  ;
```

This reads values up to 5 per line.